# Invalid MailChimp List ID: 3b27444534

Tags: extension, error, mailchimp

Good morning,

I was trying to sync my contacts from CiviCRM to Mailchimp, but I get the following error Invalid MailChimp List ID: 3b27444534. After a while, the syncing process does not progress at all. Do you have any solution to this issue?

Thank you very much,

Best Regards,

Alberto

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue is known by the maintaining developers for the mailchimp extension. Please see https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/129 and run through the steps they've suggested on there.

If it leads to a fix, it would be great if you could come back and post your solution on SE!